# How can I set the value of a static property per inherited class in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance, static, late-binding

I found out that due to inheritance static properties are shared in sibling classes even when called in `static` context instead of `self`

```
abstract class Repository {
 protected static ?string $tableName = NULL;

 protected static getTableName(): string {
  if(static::$tableName){
   return static::$tableName;
  }
  $tableName = "";
  // business logic
  static::$tableName = $tableName;
 }
}
```

```
final class UserRepository extends Repository {
}

final class CompanyRepository extends Repository {
}
```

So if `UserRepository::getTableName` is called, even `CompanyRepository::tableName` is set to "user" eg, so that the `if(static::$tableName){` will be `TRUE` in `CompanyRepository` context and `CompanyRepository::getTableName` will return "user" as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to overcome this behaviour there are two solutions:

- Redeclare the static property in each inherited class
- Create a hash table with inherited class names as keys

**Solution #1**

```
final class UserRepository extends Repository {
 protected static ?string $tableName = NULL;
}
```

Where the code in abstract `Repository` works as is

**Solution #2**

Leave the inherited classes as is while change the abstract class as:

```
abstract class Repository {
 protected static array $tableName = [];

 protected static getTableName(): string {
  // Using `isset` for older versions
  if(isset(static::$tableName[static::class])){
   return static::$tableName[static::class];
  }
  $tableName = "";
  // business logic
  static::$tableName[static::class] = $tableName;
 }
}
```